# Placing a model relative to another

Tags: libgdx

I was wondering if it's possible to position a model relative to another model? For example, I have a height map model that I generated. I would like to place a box in the center of the map, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
boxInstance.transform.set(mapInstance.transform).translate(x, y, z);
```

Where `x, y, z` is the location relative to the parent model instance.